# How to compare values in a column and a row in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I'm cleaning my dataset, and trying to match the first row and the first column's name.

For example,

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X7
X1 1  3  4  5  1
X2 1  1  2  3  4
X3 1  1  2  4  5 
X6 4  2  3  2  3
```

In this case, I want to compare X1, X2, X3, X4, X7 (first row) and X1, X2, X3, X6 (first column) to see if some numbers are in the row but not in the column (and the opposite as well). (i.e. X4 is in the column but not in the row, and X6 is in the row but not in the column)

Does anybody have a good syntax for it?

And is there any way to find the number that belongs to both the column and row?
It will be great to know if I can find it.

Comment: Do you want to compare column names and row names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand what you're asking correctly the code below should work for your sample dataframe. The output will be saved to `not_in_column` and `not_in_row`.

```
df <- data.frame(X1=c(1,1,1,4), X2=c(3,1,1,2), X3=c(4,2,2,3), X4=c(5,3,4,2), X7= c(1,4,5,3))
rownames(df) <- c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X6")

not_in_column <- rownames(df)[!(rownames(df) %in% colnames(df))]
not_in_row <- colnames(df)[!(colnames(df) %in% rownames(df))]
```